# Can two rectangular matrices multiply to have an eigenvalue of -1?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm currently in an engineering class where the professor has stated without proof that $I + AB$ is always invertible. This is where, if $I$ is $n\times n$ then $A$ is $n \times m$ and B is $m \times n$ such that $m \not = n$. He's confident enough in this identity that we're also allowed to use it without proof, but it doesn't sit well with me. I've attempted to prove it, but my attempts repeatedly lead me to the issue that this wouldn't be invertible if $AB$ has eigenvalue -1.

Here's the most direct way I attempted to go about showing invert-ability:

$det(I+AB) = det(AB - \lambda I)$ where $\lambda := -1$.

We see that if $AB$ has this eigenvalue

$det(AB + I) = 0 \implies \not \exists (AB +I)^{-1}$

My other attempts at showing this have eventually reduced down to whether $AB$ has this eigenvalue after more work. I think it's entirely possible that this inverse doesn't exist in this case and we're just assuming $AB$ doesn't have this eigenvalue whenever we use it. In my mind, the only other possibility is that two non square matrices cannot multiply to have an eigenvalue of -1, though I can't make sense of this. Any guidance in proving / disproving this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to write down simple $A$ and $B$ with $AB$ diagonal and whatever entries you desire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is not true. Let $n = 1$, $m = 2$, $A = [1, 0]$, $B$ the transpose of $[-1, 0]$. Then $I + AB = [1] + [-1] = [0]$, so is not invertible.